# calculating the mean and std on an array of torch tensors

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, torch

I am trying to calculate to mean and std for an array of torch tensors. My dataset has 720 training images and each of these images has 4 landmarks with X and Y representing a 2D point on the image.

```
to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()

landmarks_arr = []

for i in range(len(train_dataset)):
    landmarks_arr.append(to_tensor(train_dataset[i]['landmarks']))
                     
mean = torch.mean(torch.stack(landmarks_arr, dim=0))#, dim=(0, 2, 3))
std = torch.std(torch.stack(landmarks_arr, dim=0)) #, dim=(0, 2, 3))



print(mean.shape)
print("mean is {} and std is {}".format(mean, std))
```

Result:

```
torch.Size([])
mean is nan and std is nan
```

There is a couple of problems above:

1. Why to_tensor is not converting the values between 0 and 1?
2. how to calculate mean correctly?
3. Should I divide by 255 and where?

I have:

```
len(landmarks_arr)
    
720
```

and

```
landmarks_arr[0].shape

torch.Size([1, 4, 2])
```

and

```
landmarks_arr[0]

tensor([[[502.2869, 240.4949],
         [688.0000, 293.0000],
         [346.0000, 317.0000],
         [560.8283, 322.6830]]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From the pytorch docs of ToTensor():

> Converts a PIL Image or numpy.ndarray (H x W x C) in the range [0, 255] to a
> torch.FloatTensor of shape (C x H x W) in the range [0.0, 1.0] if the PIL Image
> belongs to one of the modes (L, LA, P, I, F, RGB, YCbCr, RGBA, CMYK, 1) or if the
> numpy.ndarray has dtype = np.uint8
>
> In the other cases, tensors are returned without scaling.

Since your Landmark values are not a PIL image, and not within [0, 255], no scaling is applied.

2. Your calculation appears correct. It seems, that you might have some NaN value within your data.

You can try something like

```
for i in range(len(train_dataset)):
    landmarks = to_tensor(train_dataset[i]['landmarks'])
    landmarks[landmarks != landmarks] = 0  # this will set all nan to zero
    landmarks_arr.append(landmarks)
```

within your loop. Or assert for nan within the loop to find the culprit(s):

```
for i in range(len(train_dataset)):
    landmarks = to_tensor(train_dataset[i]['landmarks'])
    assert(not torch.isnan(landmarks).any()), f'nan encountered in sample {i}'  # will trigger if a landmark contains nan
    landmarks_arr.append(landmarks)
```

3. No, see 1). You could divide by the max coordinates of the landmarks though to constrain them to [0, 1] if you so desire.

[image]

Comment: why should I divide by max coordinate if to_tensor is already putting them between [0, 1]?

Comment: because `toTensor` is putting the **PIL images** between [0,1]. Your target/landmarks will be left unaffected. So if you want to normalize your landmark into [0,1], you can divide by the max coordinate.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-19e49f3367ed> in <module>
      7 for i in range(len(train_dataset)):
      8     landmarks = to_tensor(train_dataset[i]['landmarks'])
----> 9     assert(not torch.isnan(landmarks).any()), f'nan encountered in sample {i}'  # will trigger if a landmark contains nan
     10     landmarks_arr.append(landmarks)
     11 

AssertionError: nan encountered in sample 56

Comment: It would certainly be more efficient to calculate the maximum over the whole array, rather than looping through the individual entries.